PayPal API - Sending partner-referrals keeps coming back as Unauthorised
I Have this in my payload:
            {
        "tracking_id": "868gkjhkhjlklj",
        "operations": [{
            "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
            "api_integration_preference": {
                "rest_api_integration": {
                    "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
                    "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
                    "third_party_details": {
                        "features": [
                            "PAYMENT",
                            "REFUND"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }],
        "products": [
            "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"
        ],
        "legal_consents": [{
            "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
            "granted": true
        }]
        }

I'm receiving the token from:
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

But passing the information I get Unauthorised:
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer " + jsonResponseBody.access_token);

        StringContent contentJson = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response2 = await client.PostAsync("v2/customer/partner-referrals", contentJson);
        //response2.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        response2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseBody2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var t = "";
    }

The error i get is:
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://api- 
m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals', Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
 Authorization: Authorization Bearer 

A21AALp94ZDjU22fSWX9XOB5kz4ZnyIvvKjIqL3GJNwcwnY8zyuO1a_vEmbNXPY8gSSgDIg7Jl3ixQgHePZtF6bVLVoOuWF_Q
traceparent: 00-544a1c50b287d4dd16c81e32f841d053-81f9ea5e4ec92e07-00
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 703
}}
status code: System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

In postman I get:
{
"name": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
"debug_id": "c558663a13fcd",
"message": "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",
"details": [
    {
        "issue": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
        "description": "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions."
    }
]
}

How can I fix this, what I'm trying to do is test these api calls so that I can get the onboarding URL for the seller.
Postman I have Authorisation tab as:
No Auth


And the Bearer Token in post man:

